# scala can't access android classes

Tags: android, eclipse, scala

So I have an android aplication written in scala and I work in eclipse ( Juno with scala, android sdk and AndroidProguardScala)

why does eclipse complain about (it can't find that static member)

```
ListView.INVALID_POSITION
```

while in java files this works great?

I don't mind not having autocomplete, but Eclipse complains and I can't compile the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because INVALID_POSITION belongs to android.widget.AdapterView class. So in Scala you should write direct: `AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION`

Comment: Thank you, But if that class is inherited, the ListView class should still have that visible, I mean why is it different?

Comment: When we write in Java `ListView.INVALID_POSITION` inheritance not working here at all. Compiler later just put real value for us. It is just in same scope. But scala doesn't have static members, and we should access to object value (AdapterView class) instead. Please correct me if I am wrong...